# numpy and pytables changing values when only using some specific columns

Tags: python, csv, numpy, hdf5, pytables

I have some problem when reading a csv file and then reordering the data into different hdf5 tables. However, I noticed that the values in the csv file did not match those in the hdf5 tables, and managed to make a small example of the problem.

The csv file I use look like this, table names and values, called `test.csv`:

```
a,b,c,d
1,10,3,5
2,15,5,7
3,20,7,12
4,25,9,25
```

I read this using numpy.genfromtxt. Then I create a hdf5 file using pytables. The code for that I use is as follows:

```py
import numpy
import tables

csv = 'test.csv'
data = numpy.genfromtxt(csv, delimiter=",", names=True)

hdf = 'out.h5'

file = tables.open_file(hdf, mode="a")
group = file.create_group('/', 'test', 'test')

table = file.create_table(group, 'test', data, 'test data')
table = file.create_table(group, 'test2', data[['a', 'b']], 'test data')
```

This creates two tables in the hdf5 file, `test`and `test2`. With `test` containing all the columns in `test.csv` and `test2`only containing the `'a'` and `'b'` columns.

However, when I open the hdf5 file in a viewer, it looks like this:

test1

[image: <code>test</code>]

test2

[image: <code>test2</code>]

Notice the values in `test2` being all scrambled and wrong.

I have made a work around, but it is slow and requires looping over all values in python, so I would rather understand why this is happening and if there is any particular solution to the problem, and a way to get the correct values in `test2`.

I am using Python 3.5.3, numpy 1.14.0 and pytables 3.4.2.

Comment: It's probably the multifield indexing in 1.14.  Developers have been fiddling with that, and `pytables` hasn't adjusted.  The `test2` values are first 8 values of a flattened `data`.  You may have to build a new 2 field array, and copy values by field name.

Comment: This save works for me with `h5py`.  I don't have `pytables` installed at the moment on this machine, so can't test that.